# BluetoothLEDevice on Hololens with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, hololens

I'm trying to read sensor data from a BLE Device but am entirely new to Unity / C# / HoloLens / UWP.

My used namespaces from UWP:

```
#if NETFX_CORE
using System;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth;
#endif
```

Here's the event handler for BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.Received:

```
#if NETFX_CORE
private async void Watcher_Received(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher sender, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs args)
{

    Debug.Log("=Received Advertisement=");
    ulong bluetoothAddress = args.BluetoothAddress;
    Debug.Log("  BT_ADDR: " + bluetoothAddress);
    Debug.Log("  Local name: " + args.Advertisement.LocalName);
    Debug.Log("  advertisement type: " + args.AdvertisementType.ToString());

    // Throws 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
    BluetoothLEDevice device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(bluetoothAddress);
}
#endif
```

Everything I see in my stacktrace is:

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in
>   System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll The system cannot find the file
>   specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

I do not know how to further debug this, or what's wrong in general.

Comment: what is the value of bluetoothAddress object?

Comment: 92823078933695 is what the args.BluetoothAddress holds.

Comment: have u enabled the bluetooth capability in ur project app manifest?

Comment: As I'm building the project from Unity, I have Bluetooth as a capability set in the project settings. Edit: <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth" /> is in the app manifest

Comment: I have never used unity, but make sure bluetooth capability is enabled in your uwp project as well.

Comment: It is also enabled in the uwp project itself

Comment: You need to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46721885/3785314) and [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/125976/view.html) post. They should help you find the issue.

Comment: I have the exception checked in the settings and it is thrown from FromBluetoothAddressAsync, but the output isnt any more detailed than before

Comment: Can you have a try the `BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync` method in a UWP app on the desktop device to see whether it works well?

Comment: The same code works well on three other desktops I've tried. It just doesnt work on the Hololens, but I have found a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my particular case, going to System -> Devices (HOLOLENS) and removing all previously paired bluetooth devices fixes the issue.

In my case, I only had the "Clicker" for the Hololens in the device list. Upon removing it the

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException

is not thrown anymore and

```
BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync
```

seems to work.
The clicker was not anywhere near or on, just had been paired *previously* (a couple of weeks ago).

This error is always reproducible on my end by:

- pairing the clicker
- pairing the other Gatt device

Upon calling BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync, System.IO.FileNotFoundException is thrown again, even if clicker is unpaired. When I remove the clicker from the devices list, it works again.