# Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileLoadException' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common.dll AND System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, xunit

I hope you can help me get my xUnit project up and running.

```
using SortingAlgorithms;
using Xunit;

namespace SortingArlgorithmsTest
{
    public class SortingAlgorithmsTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void SwapTest()
        {
            int[] values = { 1, 0 };
            int[] expected = { 0, 1 };
            SelectionSort.Swap(values, 0, 1);
            Assert.Equal(values[0], expected[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, a simple example of a test, but running it, leads to following messages in Output:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileLoadException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll  
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileLoadException' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common.dll
```

and this:

```
[11/28/2018 09:45:52 Informational] ------ Run test started ------
[11/28/2018 09:46:02 Warning] No test is available in <folders>\SortingArlgorithmsTest.dll. 
Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
[11/28/2018 09:46:03 Informational] ========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:10.5896982) ==========
```

following NuGet Packages are installed:

[image]

I've already searched on my own, but have not found a solution to get my tests up and running, for example:
[C# .NET Core How to debug System.IO.FileNotFoundException in System.Private.CoreLib.dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721530/c-sharp-net-core-how-to-debug-system-io-filenotfoundexception-in-system-private/46721885#46721885)

I hope you can help me. :)

edit:

ok i moved from trying to run the test from within the IDE to command with dotnet test... and something strange shows up... the folder is not there but in windows explorer it is... Maybe it is because it is not fully synced ( i use the cloud service of my university to store my private projects)
intelliJ with jUnit is not such a b***h....

for fun cmd: dir shows all old folders which are not synced anymore, but non of the folders which are in sync (or not fully synced)... in Windows explorer i have all folders...

Comment: What kind of framework do you use? Net Core or full Framework?

Comment: I use the .Net Core Framework

Comment: Try use `dotnet restore`. Also is `<folders>\SortingArlgorithmsTest.dll` your real output or you replaced your real path with `<folders>`?

Answer (score 0):

I did a *Clean* then *Build* of my *Unit Test* project and it worked with no particular reason. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the project doesn't exist anymore, so i am not able to test it.